# Remove --add-forward-port rule in firewall-cmd

Tags: redhat, firewall-cmd

Some time ago I added below rule for local port forwarding

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=3000
```

How can I remove this rule now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove it just as it was added:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=3000
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reloading you can also change runtime settings and then make it permanent

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=3000
# firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

Comment: You need to remove the `--permanent` option from the first command, otherwise, this will result in no change.